# Are Random Forests Turing-Complete?

Tags: algorithms, randomized-algorithms, turing-completeness

Is the random forests algorithm Turing-complete? As in, can any algorithm be represented by a given "tree" in the forest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Random forests are useful only for inputs of a given size, so they are not really eligible for Turing-completeness. However, any function on inputs of size $n$ can be computed by a decision tree, so in that sense the model is complete (though in practice we limit the depth of the trees).

Answer (score 5):

No, they're not Turing complete.  The handle inputs of a fixed size.  Also, they can't loop, so will always halt -- it follows that they don't have the ability to perform Turing-complete computation.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful suggestion, @DavidRicherby -- I agree, pointing that out explicitly is a nice improvement.